# How to fix jobs conflict in transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

Have two multiple geographically distributed SQL Server Databases with transactional replication.SQL Server agent sync two servers every 1 minute.After working for 10 minutes on server B (subscriber),it has an error, which lasts 10-15 minutes and corrected herself. Then again it working 10 minute and has an error. On server A (publication) I have log backup schedule it runs every 10 minutes. Maybe there is conflict between two jobs ?

```
SQLServerAgent Error: Request to run job XXX (from User sa) 
refused because the job is already running from a request by Schedule 14 (Replication agent schedule.).
Changed database context to 'XXX'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe your log backup schedule starts job XXX?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert no it just do log backup, nothing more

Comment: What is a job XXX: replication log reader, snapshot agent or distribution agent?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert this is subscriber server job , type Replication Distributor

Comment: Is synchronization schedule repeat every 1 minute? Not "run continuosly"?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert yes it's schedulet every 1 minute

Comment: It seems that subscriber server job works more then 1 minute while log is backuping and that's why this error occurs. Maybe you chould try to increase interval. Or change synchronization schedule to run continuously.

Comment: @GaaraofDesert thank you , i will increase interval and test

Comment: Try To restart the SQL Agent in all servers